# Implement Parallax Effect With ListView In Android

Tags: android

I have been trying this [Tutorial By Antoine Merle](http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/) but was unable to compile it correctly. 
Here is the screen shot `RelativeLayout`which serve as an image with `stickyheader` attached to it and a `listview` after it

[image]

Please I dont know how to set up the right class, what to extend, what to implement, the variables am just totally stocked. 
Please I need a helping hand.

My class is like this

```
     public class Profile_Activity extends Activity  {

        int mCurrentTranslation;
    //error Cannot resolve symbol StickyListView

        StickyListView mListView;
        ImageView mStickyHeader;



 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.stickyheaders);

        mListView = (StickyListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mStickyHeader = findViewById(R.id.header_imageview);
        mHeader = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header, mListView, false);
        mListView.addHeaderView(mHeader);




    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                         int totalItemCount) {
        if(visibleItemCount == 0) return;
        if(firstVisibleItem != 0) return;

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.header_imageview);
       // mImageView.setTranslationY(-mListView.getChildAt(0).getTop() / 2);
        mImageView.setCurrentTranslation(mListView.getChildAt(0).getTop());

    }
    public void setCurrentTranslation(int currentTranslation) {
        mCurrentTranslation = currentTranslation;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(0, -mCurrentTranslation / 2)  ;
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }


    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-listview fallow this one

Comment: An image was used as the header, while in the above a layout was used. My main issue is how to implement it so as to really understand how it works. From looking at the codes, its not very much complex to understand if the code is completed. Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parallex effect `design` library has provided very good layouts. It can be implemented using `CoordinatorLayout`. Instead of `ListView` you can use `RecyclerView`. Please find more details from [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout).

Comment: Its a good library, but I want to understand the work ability of the codes in respect to parallax effect and sticky header. The tutorial above seems to be simple to understand if the code is complete. Please can you help me with the complete code? I know there are lots of library out there that are better than what I want in function, but understanding is my main aim. Thank you.

Comment: I can't help you with code in any of the option. You will able to find very good tutorials for Coordinator Layout.

Comment: Ok,  please point me to any good resources on that.. Thank you.

Comment: Link given in answer contains detailed description of every possible layouts, you can design many different flavors of Stick header, just by setting different attributes. It contains sub-links also.

Comment: Thank you! Please how can I initialize these variables in this [http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/]link mListView, mStickyHeader, mHeader please help me. Am stock for days.

Comment: Thank you! Please how can I initialize these variables in this [http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/] link mListView, mStickyHeader, mHeader and mHorizontalScrollViewContainer please help me. Am stock for days.

Comment: Or should I start a new topic pls?

Comment: It is already mentioned in 3rd code snippet under Sticky Header.

Comment: Its giving me error that Cannot resolve symbols...  Am sorry am  a beginner just trying to learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101401/discussion-between-arth-tilva-and-mande-kira).